# "Before the `catch` block is executed, the runtime checks for `finally` blocks.", what does it mean?

Tags: c#, exception

From [official document about the exception handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/using-exceptions):

> Before the `catch` block is executed, the runtime checks for `finally` blocks.

I feel like the author want to say: "*the `finally` blocks are executed before the `catch` block*".

But this code does the opposite:

```
try
{
    throw new Exception();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("In the catch block.");
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine("In the finally block.");
}
// Output:
// In the catch block.
// In the finally block.
```

What does that statement really mean?

Comment: ... which is what is wondered about in [issue #9105](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/9105), opened on Nov 18, 2018

Comment: Yes, that's a documentation bug. Nice find @HansKeﬆing

Comment: Not too difficult to find, it is below the documentation that this question links to

Answer (score 2):

This is a "bug" in the documentation. The issue was filed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/9105).

The appropriate `catch` block (if any) is executed *before* a potential `finally` block of the same try-catch-finally construct.

Comment: There certainly *are* `finally` blocks executed before the `catch`, as I've indicated in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54880600/15498).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I agree with your example... but if that's what was meant by the documentation, wow, that's one mess of not explaining properly what was meant. I added a few words that clarifies what I thought was implicit knowledge.

Comment: yeah, like I've said in a comment, it appears they were trying to describe two-pass exception handling but left a few

Answer (score 2):

It's very ambiguously worded. What they were trying to indicate is that any `finally` blocks of any *nested* `try` blocks<sup>1</sup> (that didn't have a matching `catch` block for the exception) will be executed, then the `catch` block that matched the `exception` (and then its own `finally`, obviously, unless it throws another exception that is uncaught and the runtime is torn down, which can happen).

This prints `A`, `B`, `C`:

```
try {
  try {
    throw new Exception();
  }
  catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("No!");
  }
  finally
  {
    Console.WriteLine("A");
  }
}
catch (Exception ex2)
{
  Console.WriteLine("B");
}
finally
{
  Console.WriteLine("C");
}
```

The clue it's not talking about it's own `finally` is that it refers to `finally` block***s*** - a plural. Since each `try` can only have one `finally`, it must be referring to other `finally` blocks.

---

<sup>1</sup>Whether within the `try` block itself or inside other code called by the `try`.

Comment: So the flow is: codes in `try` -> in `catch` right after `try` (if it matches the exception) -> in `finally` right after -> in another `catch` (outside the current try statement like your example, or in the parent calling method) if the current `catch` don't match the exception. Am I right?

Comment: @Messi - basically, the documentation is doing a bad job of describing two-pass exception handling. An exception is thrown. In the first pass, the system goes looking for a suitable exception handler (`catch` block) but nothing else is touched yet. If it doesn't find one at all, it may tear down the process and no more code runs. However, if it finds a handler, it does the second pass. This time, it does *stack unwinding*, and as part of this it calls the `finally` clauses as it works it's way up to reach the right `try` block with the matching `catch` handler.

Comment: @Messi - so no `finally`s of nested `try`s are executed until we know a handler is going to `catch` it.

Comment: After some searching about the stack unwinding, I think it's clearly for me now. I think I got it. Thank you.